# replace entire string if a substring matches in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to replace a string if a substring matches the part of a string, but not able to achieve it. What would be the regex to match entire string from a substring.
Here is my code and the file on which i am trying to apply it to.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
STR='Server'
RSTR='puppetserver'
{ while IFS='=' read name ip
    do
        if [[ "$STR" == *${name}* ]]; then
        sed -i -e "s/*${name}*/${RSTR}/g"
        echo "Replaced with ${RSTR}."
fi
    done
} < file.txt
```

**file.txt**

```
Puppet-Agent-01 = 18.208.175.32
Puppet-Agent-02 = 18.207.194.126
Puppet-Agent-03 = 3.86.54.233
Puppet-Server-01 = 54.224.89.3
```

Comment: What is the expected result of your script.  I'm also noticing that you appear to be using `$name` (the thing that you read from the file) as part of a pattern to match `$STR` against, rather than the other way around.  This is highly unusual.

Comment: See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: I am trying to replace the string 'Puppet-Server-01' in file.txt with the string 'puppetserver'. So if i find the substring 'Server' in the read variable name like string 'Puppet-Server-01', then it should do the replacement.

Comment: It seems like you're actually trying to replace a substring matching on a shorter substring.  Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to replace everything up to = with 'puppetserver '.  Thus preserving the space before '=' Is that right ?

Comment: @PatrickTaylor, yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
Puppet-Agent-01 = 18.208.175.32
Puppet-Agent-02 = 18.207.194.126
Puppet-Agent-03 = 3.86.54.233
Puppet-Server-01 = 54.224.89.3
```

```
$ awk -F ' = ' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 ~ /Server/ { $1 = "puppetserver" }; 1' file
Puppet-Agent-01 = 18.208.175.32
Puppet-Agent-02 = 18.207.194.126
Puppet-Agent-03 = 3.86.54.233
puppetserver = 54.224.89.3
```

This treats your file as a set of   `=` -delimited lines.  When the first field matches `Server`, it is replaced by the string `puppetserver`.  The lines are then outputted.

Taking the strings `Server` and `puppetserver` from shell variables:

```bsh
awk -v patstring="$STR" -v repstring="$RSTR" -F ' = ' \
    'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 ~ patstring { $1 = repstring }; 1' file
```

or from environment variables:

```bsh
export STR RSTR
awk -F ' = ' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 ~ ENVIRON["STR"] { $1 = ENVIRON["RSTR"] }; 1' file
```

Using `sed` instead:

```bsh
sed 's/^[^=]*Server[^=]*=/puppetserver =/' file
```

This matches the string `Server`, possibly surrounded by non-`=` characters, up to a `=` character, and replaces that with `puppetserver =`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. sorry for lack of clarity in my reply. 
The output i need is as follows for which i am trying to do the substitution

`
puppetclient = 18.208.175.32
puppetclient = 18.207.194.126
puppetclient = 3.86.54.233
puppetserver = 54.224.89.3
`

Comment: @RaviKumarCH This is not what your question says. Also, I have shown how to deal with the server lines, so it would be easy to do the same for the client.

Comment: understood. Thank you very much for providing an alternate solution to achieve the result.